# GDB continue command automate

Tags: c, gdb

how to automate gdb execution with "continue command" for multiple signal events?.I have multiple signal exceptions occurring in the code and i have written signal handlers for all the signal exceptions.
when i run the program using gdb i need to each time manually enter "continue" whenever it gets signal event.after I enter continue it continues and catches next signal event and so on , till the end of the program.
i wanted to automate this program execution in gdbinit and get all the data required for debugging for all the signal events.
if there is any method to do this.Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `continue` through signals, use the following command in your `.gdbinit` file for EACH signal of interest:

```
handle SIGNAL_OF_INTEREST nostop
```

To print a message when a signal occurs, use the following command:

```
handle SIGNAL_OF_INTEREST print
```

For more information, see the [GDB manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html).

Comment: Happy to help - if it solved your problem, please click the check mark to the left of the answer :)